# Query for how to join two tables with sum oparation in one table condition based on another table?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql.
I have one table which have one column accId.In the second table we have multiple records with this accId and have another column like is amount.

I want query for sum of amount column for second table based on accId of first table.

Please help me to go forward.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up some tutorials on Joins and aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the two tables on the common attribute and then group the result on that same common attribute and add the corresponding amounts.

For more insight see:

[MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)
[MySQL GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

You should be able to write the right query after looking at those links.